# PHP rename/copy...file_put/get_contents?

Tags: php, copy, rename, file-get-contents

I have tried a whole wack of fixes for my problem but haven't encountered a solution that works...
The problem is simple...
Let's say you have this directory structure:

```
/website
  /admin
    /phpscript.php
  /img
    /folder1
      /image1.png
      /image2.png
```

What I am basically trying to do is: 
Create a folder...eg: folder2

```
/website
  /admin
    /phpscript.php
  /img
    /folder1
      /image1.png
      /image2.png
    /folder2
```

and then move image1 and image2 into folder2

The php script is located in **admin** which is where I have designed the move action to be performed.

I have tried:
`rename('../img/folder1/image1.png', '../img/folder2/image1.png');` which failed

`copy('../img/folder1/image1.png', '../img/folder2/image1.png');` which also failed


I can use copy and rename when the path to the file is the same...eg:

`rename('../img/folder1/image1.png', '../img/folder1/image3.png');`

This renamed image1.png to image3.png (image1.png no longer existed on the server and image3.png was created by the server)

`copy('../img/folder1/image1.png', '../img/folder1/image3.png');`

This made a duplicate of image1.png called image3.png (both image1.png and image3.png were on the server)
There's all permissions on folders in the apache server
...And I noticed that you can do:

```
file_get_contents('../img/folder1/image1.png')
and then do
file_put_contents('../img/folder2/image1.png')
```

as long as the folder exists...for some reason it doesn't like to move when mkdir() is used right before the file_put_contents()

This is basically my code:

```
$path = "img/"; //Generated somewhere in code above
$old_folder = "folder1/"; //Generated somewhere in code above
$folder = "folder2/"; //Generated somewhere in code above

$tmp_old_path = "../$path$old_folder";
$tmp_new_path = "../$path$folder";

mkdir($tmp_new_path);

$FP = scandir($tmp_old_path);

foreach ($FP as $key => $val){
    if($val != '.' && $val != '..'){
        $str_contents = file_get_contents($tmp_old_path.$val);
        file_put_contents($tmp_new_path.$val, $str_contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Failed" how? Any error messages?

Comment: Are you working on Linux or Windows?You should check the folder2 permission if using Linux.

Comment: Does your script have write permissions on folder2?

Comment: failed = returned false/nothing happened
I'm working on windows (apache server) all permissions available
I should edit this to say that I am using mkdir(); to create new folders...

Comment: Activate error reporting and/or look at your logs. Usually there's a warning generated if a file can't be moved/accessed/opened.

Comment: Ive added my actual code (pretty much)  
No errors in the error reporting

Comment: Why does file_put_contents() work when creating the folder manually on the server but not after using mkdir()???...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question...

and it was a permissions problem on the server I was using.

I was able to transfer to another server and I am now able to use the rename function.

Now I know -.-

```
$old_folder = 'image/folder1';
$new_folder = 'image/folder2';

rename($old_folder, $new_folder);
```

It's usually permission problems from what I've seen online...derp!

Comment: I removed the mkdir() as well...Don't need it since rename uses it implicitly.  The server I was using made it impossible to create a folder with public write permissions. So I switched to another server and that fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

Try with below snippet. Make sure you've enough permission to execute `exec` command

```
<?php
$cmd = 'mv "../img/folder1/image1.png" "../img/folder2/image1.png"';
exec($cmd, $output, $return_val);

if ($return_val == 0) {
   echo "success";
} else {
   echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: In case of `rename` (default behavior in most of linux flavored server) it implicitly calls the `mkdir()` , if destination path does not exists, but fails to give file permission. so need to call `chmod` explicitly